# Accessing the phonegap html page from my website

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am developing a website using angularjs, expressjs, mongodb.
My html, css, js files are not placed inside www root folder of phonegap. I am planning to place few html pages inside www root folder just want to check if we can access these html pages from my website. If yes then how?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want to use the App as a web browser to access your website?

Comment: Ya that i know its possible and i have already done that...i have placed only 1 html file  let say login screen under www assets folder of phonegap framework from there i am able to call my website which is hosted somewhere..now my question is if i keep some other html pages under www assets folder how can i access those html pages which are stored in devices from my website..let me know if the scenario is bit confusing i can elaborate more